# What are the frameworks that allow to draw(NOT CODE!) user interface in java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Software similar to Dreamweaver - where you just draw lines/buttons etc and the code is generated for me?

Reversed programming - not coding but drawing and the program will 'generate' the code for me?

Do you know guis like that in java?

Comment: It seems like all the major IDEs can do this.

Comment: I would be very careful about using any form designer BEFORE having a firm understanding of how a GUI works in Swing.  The designers are great tools, but they are only as good as the developer using them.

Comment: Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend `JFormDesigner`, it's a plugin for Eclipse/Netbeans/IntelliJ IDEA.

I'm using it at work with IDEA, on a project originally designed with NetBeans. Before getting it, I was just looking for some plugin to IDEA so that I wouldn't have to switch IDEs, and it was the only one I found.. But, I gave it a shot, and it converted the NetBeans project without errors. I have had some issues with getting the appearance right (positioning/stretching), but I think it was more due to poor layout type choices from my predecessors, upon rebuilding part of the window with a different layout type it worked great. Also includes some custom layouts that are nice to work with.

So all in all, works like a charm :)

Costs a bit of money, but they have a discounted price for non-commercial use.

http://www.formdev.com/jformdesigner/

Answer (score 3):

Netbeans has a Swing designer.

Doesn't come much easier than that.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans has its own intergrated Swing GUI builder, and eclipse has a similar plugin; see http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/.

It is recommended however to code a GUI yourself, since GUI builders generate a lot of unnecessary and bloated code, and also usually duplicates code frequently. If you don't want to use Swing then coding the GUI yourself is pretty much your only option.

Answer (score 1):

For Eclipse there is a plugin called Windowbuilder.

http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/